# Plot data with MATLAB biplot with more than 1 color

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, color-scheme

I have 3 groups of data that had PCA performed on them as one group. I want to highlight each variable group with a different color. Prior to this I overlaid 3 biplots. This gives different colors but creates a distortion in the data as each biplot function skews the data. This caused the groups to all be skewed by different amounts, making the plot not a correct representation.

How do I take a PCA scores matrix (30x3) and split it so the first 10x3 is one color, the next 10x3 is another and the third 10x3 is another, without the data being skewed?

Comment: What do you mean by "overlaid" the 3 biplots? Did you use `hold on` and call BIPLOT 3 times for each set of data?

Comment: Yes that is what I did. Each biplot has skewed the data differently. I'm looking to plot with scatter3 or plot3 with the data that is manipulated with the biplot command. I need to make sure I can have different colors and be able to draw a line. I think my issue is that I am not well versed in the plot properties.

Comment: Did you try calling the command `axis equal` after making your 3 biplots? That may correct the "skewing" you're seeing.

Comment: @user379362: Could you expand on how the data is distorted? A picture perhaps?

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052317/configuring-biplot-in-matlab-to-distinguish-in-scatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I used to plot biplot data with different colors. The lines of code prior to plot are taken from the biplot.m file. The way biplot manipulates data is kept intact and stops skewing of data when using overlaid biplots.

This coding is not the most efficient, one can see parts that can be cut. I wanted to keep the code intact so one can see how biplot works in it's entirety.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

xxx = coeff(:,1:3); 
yyy= score(:,1:3);

**%Taken from biplot.m; This is alter the data the same way biplot alters data - having the %data fit on grid axes no larger than 1.**

[n,d2] = size(yyy);  
[p,d] = size(xxx); %7 by 3  
[dum,maxind] = max(abs(xxx),[],1);  
colsign = sign(xxx(maxind + (0:p:(d-1)*p)));  
xxx = xxx .* repmat(colsign, p, 1);  
yyy= (yyy ./ max(abs(yyy(:)))) .* repmat(colsign, 42, 1);  
nans = NaN(n,1);  

ptx = [yyy(:,1) nans]';  
pty = [yyy(:,2) nans]';  
ptz = [yyy(:,3) nans]';  

**%I grouped the pt matrices for my benefit** 

plotdataholder(:,1) = ptx(1,:);  
plotdataholder(:,2) = pty(1,:);  
plotdataholder(:,3) = ptz(1,:);  

**%my original score matrix is 42x3 - wanted each 14x3 to be a different color**

scatter3(plotdataholder(1:14,1),plotdataholder(1:14,2),plotdataholder(1:14,3),35,[1 0 0],'marker', '.');   
hold on;  
scatter3(plotdataholder(15:28,1),plotdataholder(15:28,2),plotdataholder(15:28,3),35,[0 0 1],'marker', '.') ;  
scatter3(plotdataholder(29:42,1),plotdataholder(29:42,2),plotdataholder(29:42,3),35,[0 1 0],'marker', '.');   
xlabel('Principal Component 1');  
ylabel('Principal Component 2');  
zlabel('Principal Component 3');
```

Answer (score 1):

"Skewing" is happening because biplot is renormalizing the scores so the farthest score is distance 1 .  `axis equal` isn't going to fix this.  You should use `scatter3` instead of `biplot`

```
data = rand(30,3);
group = scores(1:10,:)
scatter3(group(:,1), group(:,2), group(:,3), '.b')

hold all
group = scores(11:20,:)
scatter3(group(:,1), group(:,2), group(:,3), '.r')

group = scores(21:30,:)
scatter3(group(:,1), group(:,2), group(:,3), '.g')
hold off

title('Data')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```

Or modify your code's scatter3 lines so that the markers are different colors.  The parameter after 'marker' tells what symbol and what symbol and color to plot.  E.g. '.r' is a red dot.  See [Linespec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html) for marker and color parameters.

```
scatter3(plotdataholder(1:14,1),plotdataholder(1:14,2),plotdataholder(1:14,3),35,[1 0 0],'marker', '.b');

hold on;

scatter3(plotdataholder(15:28,1),plotdataholder(15:28,2),plotdataholder(15:28,3),35,[0 0 1],'marker', '.r') ;

scatter3(plotdataholder(29:42,1),plotdataholder(29:42,2),plotdataholder(29:42,3),35,[0 1 0],'marker', '.g');
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that the data needed to be in the transformed format of biplot -  a max score of 1. My coding above uses the biplot code and the same method you have applied.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help, but try `axis equal` after you have overlaid the plots.

Comment: What happened with the data was that multiplication by a factor. Biplot does this to make the data have the highest number be +1. Thus, it will multiply the score matrix by an individual factor for each biplot, as the multiplication factor is based off the data. What happened was I was trying to draw a line between the furthest points with the data. THe line was not matching up with the plotted point. The data was correct but the biplot altered where it was being place.I had to do was go through the biplot function, learn how it changes data and use scatter3 and plot3 - see my answer on how.