# Configuring biplot in Matlab to distinguish in scatter

Tags: matlab, plot, pca

My original `data` is a `195x22` record set containing vocal measurements of people having Parkinson's disease or not. In a vector, `195x1`, I have a `status` which is either 1/0.

Now, I have performed a PCA and I do a `biplot`, which turns out well. The problem is that I can't tell which dots from my scatter plot origin of a sick or a healthy person (I can't link it with `status`). I would like for my scatter plot to have a red dot if healthy (status=0) and green if sick (status=1).

How would I do that? My biplot code is:

```
biplot(coeff(:,1:2), ...
    'Scores', score(:,1:2), ...
    'VarLabels', Labels, ...
    'markersize', 15 ...
);
xlabel('Bi-Plot: Standardized Data');
xlabel('PCA1');
ylabel('PCA2');
```

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdShO.png)

**UPDATE (Solution):**

Solution is inspired by @Magla and code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/KHUj3DnA

With this beautiful graph:

[image]

Comment: What are the variables `coeff` and `score`? Can you provide code that is self-contained for us to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal component scores (red points) in a `biplot` are not the ones returned by the `pca` function. As the help states,

> *biplot scales the scores so that they fit on the plot: It divides each score by the maximum absolute value of all scores, and multiplies
>   by the maximum coefficient length of coefs. Then biplot changes the
>   sign of score coordinates according to the sign convention for the
>   coefs.*

You therefore can't easily use the `(X,Y)` information to find out which point belong to a category.

Here is a workaround using the `ObsLabels` option of `biplot`. `ObsLabels` assigns some user-defined data to each observation: for each point, we will assign the index corresponding to a `status` variable (a simple incrementing value). With this, you can easily modify the red points of a `biplot` - here `marker` set to square and red/green color.

The following figure

[image]

is produced by this code

```
%some data
load carsmall
x = [Acceleration Displacement Horsepower MPG Weight]; x = x(all(~isnan(x),2),:);
[coefs,score] = pca(zscore(x));

%the status vector (here zero or one)
class_pt = round(rand(size(score,1),1));

vbls = {'Accel','Disp','HP','MPG','Wgt'};

figure('Color', 'w');
hbi = biplot(coefs(:,1:2),'scores',score(:,1:2),'varlabels',vbls,...
    'ObsLabels',num2str((1:size(score,1))'));

for ii = 1:length(hbi)
    userdata = get(hbi(ii), 'UserData');
    if ~isempty(userdata)
        if class_pt(userdata) == 0
            set(hbi(ii), 'Color', 'g', 'Marker', 's');

        elseif class_pt(userdata) == 1
            set(hbi(ii), 'Color', 'r', 'Marker', 's');
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Why are the vectors also colored? is that part of the code too? if so where? I'd love to color the lines only.

Comment: @kamula Each point is associated with a `LineStyle` property set either to `none` or `-`. Setting the color of a point also sets the line color. Check `get(hbi(ii))` and `get(hbi(ii-1))` at the end of the code execution.